# Are there any standard MBS coupon stack models?

Tags: models, mbs

I need to model MBS coupon stack prices.  It would not be difficult to create something from scratch, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel (and explain why I did) if a somewhat standard model already exists.  By "somewhat standard", I mean models like those for the term structure (e.g. [Nelson-Siegel / Nelson–Siegel–Svensson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson-Siegel#Modeling_the_yield_curve) or some newer stuff by [Diebold et al](http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/YieldCurve.html)).

I would appreciate any pointers, no matter how obscure.

Comment: Hi, good question but could you please elaborate a little more on what is the payoff of a " MBS coupon stack". Regards

Comment: @TheBridge: The MBS coupon stack is the series of prices for TBA (to-be-announced) MBS at various coupons.  It's not a security, it's a set of securities (like the term structure is a set of bonds over different maturities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with any formal "models" of the TBA coupon stack similar to Nelson-Siegel, but we typically compare the TOAS and ZV (Z-spread) curves as a function of coupon and issuer/maturity.  We also examine relative value between these curves and various seasoned loan pools.  The curve itself is very erratic, and plotting it often gives a good impression of which particular points on the curve may be over/under-valued.  I have dealt with a number of market participants (traders) in this area over the years, and it seems like much is still done by guess-timating.

That said, there are a few references on TBAs generally by [Citigroup](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/17756433/%5BCitibank%5D-Guide-to-Mortgage-Back-Securities), [JPMorgan](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/17756433/%5BCitibank%5D-Guide-to-Mortgage-Back-Securities), [the Fed](http://www.ny.frb.org/research/staff_reports/sr468.pdf) and probably others.  I couldn't find a reference to a model of the TBA coupon stack in any of these.